# Is there a reliable way to start an activity on bootup in Android?

Tags: android, boot

I have tried using:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

But that is a woefully inconsistent way to start an activity on start up on the Android platform.

Is there anything GUARANTEED to start my app on start up?

Comment: May I ask? What is the underlying purpose of your activity? Is it a home launcher replacement? Does it really need to be an activity and not a service?

Comment: That is a complicated question friend. I'm making a kiosk system that uses Unity for the launcher activity and another background activity for it's functionality for security reasons. This background activity needs to be an activity because it leverages something called Samsung Knox which needs an activity to authenticate itself with user interaction. I wish I could make it a service. I just need a reliable way to start this activity though.

Comment: It's on sd scan completed.

Comment: What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to declare the permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Then catch the intent with a broadcast receiver:

In the manifest:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.mypackagename.MyBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
    android:exported="false" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In MyBroadcastReceiver.java:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, YourClass.class);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, did I not mention specifically that this method is unreliable?

Comment: how come? please explain. I have used it in numerous projects and always worked as expected

Comment: In the project I'm currently working on I've found that that event is not always fired on system boot up. It may be due to my custom launcher or something that I'm doing but in any case I asked for a solution besides that one.

Comment: The reliable method is on sd scan completed same code as above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Android Studio.

I am also creating a Service that is to run at Boot Complete and I also initially had a wholly bunch of inconsistent and unreliable results, where my Application (Service) seemed to not even try to start.

Sometimes it would work perfectly and then when I update the project with some other non-BroadcastReciever related updates, it appeared to break the Auto-Startup.

What I found was that when I went to run my app and monitored the logcat, I found that on some occasions, the Android OS Broadcast Services could take a whole 30 seconds to update with the updated Package details.

For example, from logcat...

```
03-03 17:08:26.757     681-1780/? D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart
#### Note the time stamp between the PACKAGE_REMOVED (above) and PACKAGE_ADDED (below) ####
03-03 17:08:26.825      681-681/? I/ConfigFetchService﹕ PackageReceiver: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart flg=0x8000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService$PackageReceiver (has extras) }
03-03 17:08:26.833      681-681/? I/ConfigFetchService﹕ onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
03-03 17:08:26.841      707-707/? D/PackageAddedReceiver﹕ package added com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart
03-03 17:08:26.873     681-1816/? D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart
03-03 17:08:26.877    1419-1818/? I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi﹕ Updating corpora: APPS=com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart, CONTACTS=MAYBE
03-03 17:08:27.005     681-1816/? D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart
```

And then I changed something unrelated and when I next updated the Package...

```
03-03 17:10:29.866    2454-3515/? D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED and uri=com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart
#### This time, it takes over 30 seconds to Update the Broadcast Services!!! ####
03-03 17:11:00.190    2454-2454/? I/ConfigFetchService﹕ PackageReceiver: Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart flg=0x8000010 cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService$PackageReceiver (has extras) }
03-03 17:11:00.194    2454-2454/? I/ConfigFetchService﹕ onStartCommand Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart cmp=com.google.android.gms/.config.ConfigFetchService (has extras) }
03-03 17:11:00.206    2404-2404/? D/PackageAddedReceiver﹕ package added com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart
03-03 17:11:00.222    2454-3587/? D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED and uri=com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart
03-03 17:11:00.246    3168-3589/? I/UpdateIcingCorporaServi﹕ Updating corpora: APPS=com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart, CONTACTS=MAYBE
03-03 17:11:00.326    2454-3601/? D/PackageBroadcastService﹕ Received broadcast action=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED and uri=com.test.jbyrne.anotherautostart
```

I spent many hours trying to figure out why this was so unreliably and it ultimately came down to the fact that I was rebooting my device too early, before the Android OS Broadcast Services were updated.

Try waiting for a minute before you reboot your device to test your update, to insure the various Broadcast Services are updated. Or Monitor the logcat for the

```
android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED
```

lines.

I hope this helps!!

Kind Regards,

John